# Cucumber report not being generated when IRetryAnalyzer is used as listener

Tags: testing, cucumber, testng, bdd, maven-surefire-plugin

Using IRetryAnalyzer to rerun the failed tests again. But when I add IRetryAnalyzer as a listener in surefire it does not generate html cucumber reports anymore.

I am using the following in the code.

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.masterthought</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-reporting</artifactId>
            <version>4.9.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

with sure fire plugin. This auto-generates the html report from html.

Comment: How are you configuring cucumber reporting and IretryAnalyzer in your code? That would be great If you will be able to share some piece of code. So that we could help you to fix issue

Comment: @UnknownBeast let me know if you need something else?